# How can I set the variable labels in SAS using a table?

Tags: sas, label

Suppose I am given a dataset (Table 1) with the following column names:

```
X1, X2, ... , XN
```

I have a second file (Table 2) containing the description of the variables. It look as follows:

```
Var  Description
X1   Description of X1
X2   Description of X2
.    ...
.    ...
.    ...
XN   Description of XN
```

How could I label Table 1 using Table 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little more complicated to do this in SAS than it is in R or similar; there's not a simple one-step solution.  But with some basic knowledge of macro language, it's not particularly complicated.

First, you need a macro that takes a variable name and a string as parameters.

```
%macro label_it (var=, label=);
  label  &var. = "&label.";
%mend label_it;
```

Then you need to generate a list of macro calls.  Assuming you have a dataset `varlabels` with variables `var` and `description`:

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%label_it(var=',var,',label=',description,')')
    into :labellist separated by ' '
    from varlabels;
quit;
```

Then you just use that new macro variable `&labellist.` in whatever context you prefer - data step or `PROC DATASETS`.

```
data want;
  set have;
  &labellist.;
run;
```

or

```
proc datasets lib=work;
  modify have;
  &labellist.;
run; quit;
```

There are lots of other ways to do this, but this is probably the simplest.  It's possible to do this in more-or-less one step, but it's a lot more complicated and probably slower rather than faster (using DOSUBL).